# Meta tags implementation on MeteorJS

Tags: meteor, prerender

I am maintaining a MeteorJS web app and I need to add some specific meta tags into homepage.

I see that there is a head.html in the project that has all  information, including
the existing og meta tags, I tried to add the specific meta tag there and restarted the server.

If I right click view source on the homepage, I can see the newly added meta tag.

However, if I try to use Facebook debugger to see what the FB Crawler sees, the newly added meta tag is not seen by the bot. In fact the bot sees some additional twitter meta tags that does not exist anywhere in the project.

Investigating further, I noticed the project uses a library called
`manuelschoebel:ms-seo`: https://github.com/DerMambo/ms-seo

This library is initialised in the Meteor.startup like this:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

  if(Meteor.isServer){
    if(Meteor.DEBUG){
      robots.addLine('Disallow: /');
    }
  
    robots.addLine('Disallow: /admin');
  }
  

  if(Meteor.isClient){

    // default SEO
    return SEO.config({
      title: '...',
      meta: {
        "description": "..."
      },
      og: {
        'image': '....' 
      }
    });
  }
```

Now I am guessing this SEO library is the reason why the bot does not see the newly added meta tag in the head.html.

What is the right way to add the newly meta tag in a clean way? why is this SEO library not respecting the head.html in the project?

Comment: If you see the source on the homepage to include the tags, then anyone else, including those bots, will see them, too -- at least eventually. I bet this is just a caching issue, where the bots have not yet refetched the page.

Comment: The right way to add meta tags to your Meteor app is by editing your head.html file or the likes as you're correctly doing. It's hard to say if the package is causing your tags to not appear, have you tried removing it and checking again? Also, it could be a cache issue just like @ChristianFritz said.

Answer (score 0):

The `manuelschoebel:ms-seo` package is dynamically defaulting the meta tags as it's meant to do. Though without a pre-rendering service, it's just updating them in the client which crawlers will not see, as they're inserted with javascript. They need to be baked into the `<head>` or injected from the server (i.e. loaded normally) for crawlers to see them.

If you want just one global meta tag in the `head.html` just remove the `manuelschoebel:ms-seo` package and it won't affect anything.

Not sure why you would want to do this as the idea is that you can set a default in the package defaults, then dynamically override them for specific routes/pages per the package instructions.

If you need dynamic meta tags, you'll need to do one of the following:

1. Dynamically add them based on the route/data on the client with `manuelschoebel:ms-seo` or `lookback:seo` then use the `mdg:seo` package along with [prerender.io](https://www.prerender.io) to serve a pre-rendered version of the page with the client-added dynamic meta tags. This works and it's pretty slick and easy. But you'll have to pay or roll your own prerender.io server.
2. Dynamically add them on the server to the client when the request comes in with the [server-render](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/server-rende) package. This is even easier.